# What is the difference between pkcs v1.5 padding and pkcs v2.1 padding?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, padding, public-key-encryption, pkcs#1

I have just a basic knowledge about padding techniques. For RSA padding these two padding techniques are available.

1. Can anyone explain clearly about these two padding schemes, their own pros and cons?
2. Also which padding is suitable for which type of situations?

Comment: Read this https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017

Comment: rsa is used for both signatures and encryption, and different formats are used for each. The more modern paddings, OAEP for encryption and PSS for signatures, are preferred for all scenarios over the older schemes from ver 1.5 of PKCS1. The only reason to use the older schemes is because you have to in order tom interoperate with other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

PKCS#1 v1.5: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2

PKCS#1 v2.x: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.1

You can use PKCS#1 v1.5 for signatures, but do not use it for encryption due to Bleichenbacher attack (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/can-you-explain-bleichenbachers-cca-attack-on-pkcs1-v1-5).